# Скрипт jQuery не работает, так как div отсутствует при загрузке страницы

Tags: jquery

Есть jQuery скрипт. Он измеряет ширину блока `div` и добавляет класс `newstyle`. Дело в том, что этот `div` показывается после клика на кнопку `<label class="action-button-label">`, а не сразу при загрузке страницы, и я подозреваю, что мой jQuery скрипт не работает из-за этого. Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить ситуацию?

```
var ParentWidth = $('.navigation').width();
if (ParentWidth < 565) {
    $('.navigation').addClass('newstyle');
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить ситуацию?

Поместить код из вопроса в конце обработчика клика на кнопку.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/687281)

Comment: @Spatz Сейчас Анна отметит этот ответ как самый лучший, и Вам будет стыдно.